# Is there a null-set whose translations generate the set of all null-sets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Under the Lebesgue measure, is there a null-set $N$ whose translations generate the set of all null-sets when closed under countable unions and countable intersections?

I know that such an $N$ cannot be countable, since the set of all countable sets produce nothing new under countable unions and countable intersections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. This follows from pure cardinality considerations: Since every subset of the Cantor set is a nullset, and the Cantor set is of cardinality $\frak c$, there are at least $2^{\frak c}$ nullsets (and of course at most $2^{\frak c}$ nullsets). But given a nullset $N$ there are only $\frak c$ translations of $N$ and closing under countable union and intersection won't raise this (for details see the proof that there are $\frak c$ Borel sets).

---

In the comments, bof has asked if we replace countable intersection with taking subsets, if such a magical nullset exists, and I believe the answer is still no, although there are still some issues with the proof. I'll condition on the result that for "most" $a\in[0,1]$ (it suffices to be positive measure, but I think there are countably many exceptions), $aC+b$ has measure zero in the cantor measure on $C$ (where $C$ is the $[0,1]$-Cantor set).

The trick is that these scaled Cantor sets are "unreachable" from each other; no amount of countable unions will make one big in the measure on the other. Given $N$, there are at most a nullset of $a\in[0,1]$ such that there is a $b$ with $N+b$ having measure $>0$ in the cantor measure on $aC$, because otherwise $N$ would have positive measure (not sure about justification here), and so there is an $a\in[0,1]$ such that $N+b$ has measure zero in the cantor measure on $aC$. Then any countable union of such sets and any subset of this is also measure zero in $aC$, and so $aC$ is a nullset which is missed by $N$.

Comment: Yes, but is there a null-set $N$ such that every null-set is a **subset** of a countable union of translates of $N$?

Comment: @bof I've attempted a proof of your modified question, but to be honest it's a bit out of my area of expertise and so there are still some gaps in the proof. And don't you dare ask me what happens if you also allow $N$ to be scaled, cause then I'll think you're just trolling me. ;)

Comment: By a weird coincidence, someone has asked the [same question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198122/translates-of-null-sets) over on Math Overflow as I asked in my comment.